# What does \$\small-X(f+f_{LO})\$ mean in this passive downconversion mixer?

Tags: rf, mixer

In the images below I circled one expression in red. There's supposed to be a frequency shift, but what does -X(f+f<sub>LO</sub>)/j·π mean here, and how is Y<sub>1</sub>(f) equal to the output spectra in figure 2.22(b)?

How can I compute the gain with that extra factor? A transfer function should be in the form Y=X·H but what I see is Y=(X1-X2)·H

[image]

[image]

Comment: A mixer is a time-varying system (here, the switch resistance changes with time). The transfer function (in a conventional sense) is not defined for it. The two terms in the expression for Y(f) are coming because the author considers both the positive and negative frequencies and both shift down to IF at the mixer output. The conversion gain is just the ratio of the IF voltage to the input RF voltage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That rigorous math might be simplified to a more-specific case demonstrated by this LTspice example. I hope it doesn't add confusion, because in this example \$Y_1(f) |_{I.F.} = constant\$. That is, output frequency is 0 Hz...sometimes it is useful to look at these special conditions.

- X input sine wave has peak amplitude of 1V.
- the local oscillator switch is ON 50% and OFF 50%, just like the textbook.
- local oscillator frequency is identical to X input's frequency, so this example has a \$ f_{I.F.}\$ component at 0 Hz (DC).
- local oscillator is exactly in-phase with X input

[image: LTspice trans output voltage vs time][image: LTspice commutating mixer schematic]

Note that mixer output rises exponentially toward \${V_{peak}}\times{{2}\over{\pi}}\$.
Since the switch is open half the time, the source resistance (R1=50 ohms) in combination with the 50% switch, might be viewed as a 100 ohm resistor.
The gain of this mixer is close to \${2}\over{\pi}\$ if the switch is 50%-on, 50%-off, and if switch ON-resistance is far less than R1, and if switch OFF-resistance far greater than R1. Should these three conditions deviate, gain is less.

In this example, no power is transferred to a load resistance. What load resistance absorbs maximum power? It would have to be 100 ohms.
In the example circuit, a 100 ohm load resistor in parallel with a large value smoothing capacitor  (C1) absorbed about 1mW power. That's about \$({{2}\over{\pi}})^2\$ times available power of 2.5mW.

Be aware that while the switch is open, no power is pulled from the source. While the switch is closed R1 dissipates oodles of power by virtue of C1's smoothing effect. If R1 is an antenna, power is re-radiated at many frequencies. Not good.

Very often, a second similar mixer circuit is used to take advantage of the first mixer's off-period to deliver power to the load. A phase inversion is required (often accomplished with a transformer winding) to combine both mixer outputs. Now power is delivered to the load: 50% from one mixer, 50% from the other. The optimum load resistance now becomes 50 ohms rather than 100 ohms, since it is connected 100%.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is a way to call one of the inputs of the mixer, so you have fRF and fLO being the inputs and the frequency of the output after being mixed is fRF + fLO or fRF - fLO.

I am not a hundred percent sure of the conventions in the book but I believe they just use f instead of fRF

edit: your case is a downconverter so the output frequency is fRF - fLO or f - fLO is my guess

I have not read that book, so this is just a guess.